# Como pasar de int a char en c++

Tags: c++

capaz es fácil pero no se me ocurre nada para hacer la conversión
Tengo que desarrollar la siguiente función:
`int i = 2; 
char c = intToChar(i); 
cout << c << endl;`

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que debe hacer la  función `intToChar`?

Comment: la función intToChar me tiene que devolver el valor de i, es decir 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta con consultar una tabla ASCII cualquiera para ver que los caracteres que se corresponden con dígitos númericos empiezan en 0x30, es decir:

```
0 -> 0x30
1 -> 0x31
2 -> 0x32
...
```

Es decir, para convertir un dígito a char basta con sumarle 0x30:

```
char c = i + 0x30;
```

Comment: muchas gracias bro, se agradece